# SQLite Entity Framework Core issue with saving list object

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, orm

I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm just exploring the technology along with SQLite for use in a new project.

I've run into an issue when trying to initialize my database with some dummy data.

Here are my model classes:

```
public class Format
{
    [Key]
    public int FormatId { get; set; }

    public string FormatName { get; set; }

    public string FormatType { get; set; }

    public string ValueType { get; set; }

    public List<Value> InValue { get; set; } = new List<Value> { };

    public List<Value> OutValue { get; set; } = new List<Value> { };
}

public class Value
{
    [Key]
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my database context:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Format> Formats { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=MyDatabase.db", options =>
        {
            options.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
        });

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Format>().ToTable("Formats", "test");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Format>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.FormatId);
            entity.HasMany(e => e.InValue);
            entity.HasMany(e => e.OutValue);
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And here is my initialization code:

```
public static void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        string dbName = "MyDatabase.db";
        if (File.Exists(dbName))
        {
            File.Delete(dbName);
        }
        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            //Ensure database is created
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
           

            if (!dbContext.Formats.Any())
            {
                dbContext.Formats.AddRange(new Format[]
                {
                    new Format
                    { 
                        FormatId=1, 
                        FormatName = "tm", 
                        FormatType = "VALUE", 
                        ValueType = "num", 
                        InValue = new List<Value> { new Value { ValueId = 1, ValueName = "0" }, new Value { ValueId = 2, ValueName = "1" }, new Value { ValueId = 3, ValueName = "2" } }, 
                        OutValue = new List<Value> { new Value { ValueId = 1, ValueName = "0h" }, new Value { ValueId = 2, ValueName = "1h" }, new Value { ValueId = 3, ValueName = "2h" } } 
                    },
                });
                dbContext.SaveChanges(); // crashes here
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Value' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ValueId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

It crashes when I have more than one item in the InValue and OutValue lists. You can see I have 3 items in each list. If I have one item in each list then there is no error. I think I might have missed something in the model creation but now sure what.

Answer (score 0):

To reference a table twice, you must provide the foreign IDs. In your case, there is no relationship between entities.

```
public class Format
{
    [Key]
    public int FormatId { get; set; }

    public string FormatName { get; set; }

    public string FormatType { get; set; }

    public string ValueType { get; set; }

    public List<Value> InValue { get; set; } = new List<Value> { };

    public List<Value> OutValue { get; set; } = new List<Value> { };
}

public class Value
{
    [Key]
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public string ValueName { get; set; }

    public int InFormatId { get; set;}
    public int OutFormatId { get; set;}

    public virtual Format InFormat { get; set; }
    public virtual Format OutFormat { get; set; }

}
```

Fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Value>()
               .HasOne(m => m.InFormat)
               .WithMany(t => t.InValue)
               .HasForeignKey(m => m.InFormatId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Value>()
               .HasOne(m => m.OutFormat)
               .WithMany(t => t.OutValue)
               .HasForeignKey(m => m.OutFormatId);
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

And you should add value table to DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Format> Formats { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }
    ///....
}
```

Comment: It seems like HasRequired doesn't resolve.

Comment: Which entity framework version are you using?

Comment: The only package I have installed in the project is Microsot.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite v7.0.0-preview.7.22376.2

Comment: Thanks! So now I'm getting a different error. SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'. By the way I haven't changed my Format object that I am adding.

Comment: Have you got the error while running the migration?

Comment: I have updated again, added ondelete(cascade), ther error might be  related to that.

Comment: I ran again with the OnDelete added but it's still the same error. Answering your previous question I the error while running my InitializeDatabase method. This is SQLite so as far as I'm aware it doesn't run migrations. I mean my code above is simplified but I have more tables that were created successfully. It's only the Formats table with list objects that gives this issue.

Comment: I understand you. the error is that foregin ids (inFormatId, outFormatId) are empty while record insert.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. So yes if I populate all fields of the Value class then indeed I don't get any error. But tbh I don't know the purpose of the new fields InFormatId, OutFormatId, InFormat, and OutFormat. I don't know what to populate these with. I just put some dummy data and I no longer get an error.